# @ObjectModel.text.element is not working with WITH_INTENT_BASED_NAVIGATION

Tags: annotations, abap, cds

`@ObjectModel.text.element` is not working when I use WITH_INTENT_BASED_NAVIGATION, it only shows work order description

[image]

I've tried afew things like field Group and stuff but its still not working.

```
      @Search.defaultSearchElement: true
      @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
      @ObjectModel.enabled: true
      @ObjectModel.text.element: ['WorkOrderDesc']
      @UI.lineItem:[{ position : 10,
                          label: 'Work Order',
                    importance : #HIGH,
                           type: #WITH_INTENT_BASED_NAVIGATION,
           semanticObjectAction: 'display',
                          value: 'WorkOrderNumber'
                    }]
      @Consumption.semanticObject: 'TestMaintenanceOrder'
  key WorkOrderNumber,

      @EndUserText: { label:  'Work Order Description' }
      @UI.lineItem:[{ position : 15, label: 'Work Order Description', importance : #HIGH }]
      @UI.hidden: true
      WorkOrderDesc,
```

I was hoping to have the Work order and Description in one column if its possible.

Something like this where the navigation is only for the work order number?

[image: img]

Comment: This is basically the "did you try turning it on and off again" equivalent for your problem: Did you refresh+regenerate the CDS in transaction `segw` and clear the caches in `/iwfnd/gw_client`?

Comment: *is not working* means it dosn't open order when clicked?